# How to delete corrupt folder?

Tags: windows-8.1, filesystem-corruption

I have a folder on the desktop which is about 1.6 GB in size. When I try to open it I get a message like this:

> The file or directory is corrupt or unreadable

Fortunately, I have a backup of that folder so I want to get rid of this folder. If I try to delete it, it fails to delete however I can rename the folder, move it and do whatever except deletion. I've tried various methods but could not succeed.

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Look at the disk properties from Windows Explorer
- Go to the Tools tab
- Choose Error Checking
- You will need to reboot to allow CHKDSK to run at startup
- The corrupted directory will either be restored to a readable state
  or deleted

Alternatively, the command line approach is `CHKDSK C: /B` (replace C: with your drive as appropriate)

Once run, you can tidy up as you wish.

Comment: I have OS in C drive and the corrupted folder is in C drive can i still do this ?

Comment: Important to know: if you schedule an error check after reboot it might take a very long time (depending on the size of the disk).

Comment: Thanks so much, I literally just spent an hour or two trying to figure out ways to delete a corrupted folder.

Comment: is `\B` a parameter? what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

I used the Puppy Linux bootable CD, used its file manager to locate the file and folder, clicked on the file, deleted it, then the folder.  It worked great

Answer (score -1):

Boot any Linux distribution from a USB and delete that file/folder.
Just turn off fast boot first to access your HDD from Linux.

Comment: This was suggested nearly 2 years ago.